# Return two items a field and a value from a SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server, function, return-value

I do have a challenge here, I have a table called `fileTable` with the following columns:

```
    FileID   FileName
    =================
         1  |  sdk
         2  |  mdk
         3  |  jdk
         4  |  apk
```

My challenge here is writing a function that gets passed the filename, if it does exist in the table, return a value 1 and its fileID and if not return a value 0 and ID 0

Now here is what I had started with and I thought about bringing it as a table but then got stuck when trying to use declarations or if statements inside the function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[booker](
    @filenumber nvarchar(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
     RETURN 
        (
        --NB 
        -- note the challenges am facing  i thought of passing a value of FileID to @fn then check if its empty or not, that wont work
        --- Declare @fid int;    // is not accepted inside here
        -- IF   EXISTS (SELECT @fid=FILENUMBER FROM    [dbo].[File] WHERE FILENUMBER = @filenumber)  // the if statement is wrong here too
        SELECT FileID 
        FROM [dbo].[File] 
        WHERE FileID = @filenumber 
        -- am left with the above statement where i can extract the FileID but don't know how to check if it exists and if so how to
        -- return it with a value 1 that shows the record is in and value 0, fileid=0 if there is no record
)
```

Comment: Why do you need to bring as Table?

Answer (score 0):

Use **multistatement table valued function** as below for using multiple code blocks as per your logic. You are using **inline table valued function** which allows only for single SELECT statement.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[booker](@filenumber nvarchar(50))
RETURNS @ResultTableVariable TABLE (FileID INT, IsExist INT)
AS
   BEGIN

      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[File] WHERE FileName= @filenumber)
      BEGIN
           INSERT INTO @ResultTableVariable (FileID , IsExist)
           SELECT 0 , 0 
      END 
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @ResultTableVariable (FileID , IsExist)
        SELECT FileID, 1
        FROM [dbo].[File] 
        WHERE FileID = @filenumber 
      END

   RETURN
END
```

This returns a table with two columns `FileID` and `IsExist`

Comment: Its higlingting the IF statmement  saying  that "Incorrect syntax near IF
expecting '(' SELECT,or WITH.
"
And must declare a scalar variable @filenumber and also rejects the closing bracket ')'

Comment: What you need is multistatement table valued function . Please check link ...http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/discussionofsqlserver/2012/02/15/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/

Comment: please check edit answer and see the link for matching syntax

Answer (score 0):

BUT WHEN I CHANGED mhasan's code to stored procedure it worked

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[booker](
 @filenumber nvarchar(50))

AS

  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[File] WHERE FileNumber= @filenumber)
  BEGIN
       SELECT 0 As FileID, 0 As IsExist 
  END 
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT FileID, 1 As IsExist 
    FROM [dbo].[File] 
    WHERE FileNumber = @filenumber 
  END
```

I think am going to use this for a while, thank you tho

Answer (score 0):

From your question, getting data as **Table** seems to be **invalid approach**.

You can get the data as single value in function using below query

```
CREATE FUNCITON [dbo].[booker](@filenumber nvarchar(50)) RETURNS nvarchar(10) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE fileDetail nvarchar(10);
    DECLARE @IDValue INT;

    SET fileDetail = '';
    SET @IDValue = 0;

    SELECT FileID INTO @IDValue
    FROM [dbo].[File] 
    WHERE FileID = @filenumber;

    IF IDValue = 0 THEN
        SET fileDetail := 0 +'|'+0;
    ELSE
        SET fileDetail := 1 +'|'+@IDValue;
    END IF;

 RETURN (fileDetail);
END
```

Hope this should help you out.